# Why do Kafka brokers store rebalance metadata for consumer groups in the __consumer_offsets topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

While working on a Kafka Streams application, we observed that the group coordinator broker stores rebalance metadata in the `__consumer_offsets` topic.

Since in our case we had 1200 stream threads, this metadata became huge (around 100 MB without compression and 25 MB after LZ4 compression), and since the `offsets.load.buffer.size` parameter has a default value of only 5MB, the follower brokers of the corresponding `__consumer_offsets` topic partition were not able to read. This caused the new GroupCoordinator to respond with `error_code=16 (NotCoordinatorException)` when there is a failure of the old GroupCoordinator.

Why do brokers store rebalance metadata for a consumer group in the `__consumer_offsets` topic and is there a way to disable this ?

Answer (score 1):

The group metadata is stored for fail-over reasons. If the GroupCoordinator dies and another broker takes over those groups, it needs this data to work properly. This is a consumer/broker feature and not specific to Kafka Streams.

For example, the new GroupCoordinator must know what members are in the group to apply corresponding timeouts (i.e., `session.timeout` and `max.poll.timeout`).

Thus, it's not possible to disable it, as it's essential for the cluster to work correctly. You can change the corresponding config setting to give brokers large enough memory limits to handle the group metadata.

For plain `KafkaConsumers` group metadata does usually not grow as quickly and it's usually not a problem to handle large groups. However, `KafkaStreams` adds additional metadata compared to the client and its metadata is particularly big. This is a known issue and I am sure it will be addressed in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matthias J. Sax for the reply.  
 If kafka brokers did not store group metadata in __consumer_offsets topic , then additional rebalance will be required when new group coordinator takes the role.  

So Kafka made the choice of storing metadata just to avoid one additional rebalance ?

Comment: Not sure atm, if an additional rebalance would be sufficient. Those protocols are tricky...

Comment: you mentioned that huge metadata is a known issue and gets addressed in future. Please let us know if there is any JIRA related to this task. We will be happy to take this forward.